# ELF section flags not picking up flags from linker script

Tags: c, linker, elf, msp430

In my linker script for binaries on an MSP430, I have a memory section marked "rx":

```
MEMORY {
  ROM (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x4400, LENGTH = 0xb000 /* END=0xF3FF, size 45056 */
}
```

Despite this, readelf gives me:

```
[ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000446c 000140 000500 00  WA  0   0  4
```

W is set on .rodata, despite .rodata being assigned to ROM. This confuses size,
which assumes all writable sections with initial data to be in .data, causing
an incorrect estimate of static SRAM usage. I could work around this with
objcopy, but is there a cleaner way to do it solely from the linker script?

Running `msp430-elf-objcopy --set-section-flags .rodata=CONTENTS,ALLOC,LOAD,READONLY xbdprog.bin xbdprog.bin.new` produces the following warnings:

```
msp430-elf-objcopy: test: section .text lma 0x496e adjusted to 0x5dca
msp430-elf-objcopy: test: section `.text' can't be allocated in segment 4
```

although this doesn't matter for my application, since size now picks up the correct values, and the elf file gets translated to an ihex file anyway. Still, it's "dirty". Is there a better way?

Full linker script below:

```
/* ============================================================================ */
/* Copyright (c) 2015, Texas Instruments Incorporated                           */
/*  All rights reserved.                                                        */
/*                                                                              */
/*  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without          */
/*  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions          */
/*  are met:                                                                    */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright           */
/*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.            */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright        */
/*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the      */
/*     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.     */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of      */
/*     its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived      */
/*     from this software without specific prior written permission.            */
/*                                                                              */
/*  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" */
/*  AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,       */
/*  THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR      */
/*  PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR            */
/*  CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,       */
/*  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,         */
/*  PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; */
/*  OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,    */
/*  WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR     */
/*  OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,              */
/*  EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.                          */
/* ============================================================================ */

/* This file supports MSP430F5529 devices. */
/* Version: 1.159 */
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */

/* Modified for building executables loaded through XBX bootloader */

OUTPUT_ARCH(msp430)
ENTRY(_start)

MEMORY {
  SFR              : ORIGIN = 0x0000, LENGTH = 0x0010 /* END=0x0010, size 16 */
  PERIPHERAL_8BIT  : ORIGIN = 0x0010, LENGTH = 0x00F0 /* END=0x0100, size 240 */
  PERIPHERAL_16BIT : ORIGIN = 0x0100, LENGTH = 0x0100 /* END=0x0200, size 256 */
  RAM              : ORIGIN = 0x2400, LENGTH = 0x2000 /* END=0x43FF, size 8192 */
  INFOMEM          : ORIGIN = 0x1800, LENGTH = 0x0200 /* END=0x19FF, size 512 as 4 128-byte segments */
  INFOA            : ORIGIN = 0x1980, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x19FF, size 128 */
  INFOB            : ORIGIN = 0x1900, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x197F, size 128 */
  INFOC            : ORIGIN = 0x1880, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x18FF, size 128 */
  INFOD            : ORIGIN = 0x1800, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x187F, size 128 */
  ROM (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x4400, LENGTH = 0xb000 /* END=0xF3FF, size 45056 */
  BSL              : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x0800
  USBRAM           : ORIGIN = 0x1C00, LENGTH = 0x0800
  HIROM (rx)       : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 0x000143FF
}

SECTIONS
{
  /* This is just for crt0.S and interrupt handlers.  */
  .lowtext           :
  {
    PROVIDE (_start = .);
    . = ALIGN(2);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.crt_*)))
    KEEP (*(.lowtext))
  } > ROM

  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.plt)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.lower.rodata.* .lower.rodata)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.* .const .const:*)
    *(.rodata1)

    *(.eh_frame_hdr)
    KEEP (*(.eh_frame))
    KEEP (*(.gcc_except_table)) *(.gcc_except_table.*)
    PROVIDE (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE (__preinit_array_end = .);
    PROVIDE (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array))
    PROVIDE (__init_array_end = .);
    PROVIDE (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.fini_array))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    PROVIDE (__fini_array_end = .);
    LONG(0); /* Sentinel.  */

    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of the constructors, so
       we make sure it is first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not actually link against
       crtbegin.o; the linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it doesn't matter which
       directory crtbegin.o is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin*.o(.ctors))

    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from from the
       crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.  The .ctor section
       from the crtend file contains the end of ctors marker and it
       must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend*.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))

    KEEP (*crtbegin*.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend*.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  } > ROM

  .upper.rodata :
  {
    *(.upper.rodata.* .upper.rodata)
  } > HIROM

  .data :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__datastart = .);
    *(.lower.data.* .lower.data)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.either.data.* .either.data)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    KEEP (*(.jcr))
    *(.data.rel.ro.local) *(.data.rel.ro*)
    *(.dynamic)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    KEEP (*(.gnu.linkonce.d.*personality*))
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
    *(.data1)
    *(.got.plt) *(.got)

    /* We want the small data sections together, so single-instruction offsets
       can access them all, and initialized data all before uninitialized, so
       we can shorten the on-disk segment size.  */
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.sdata .sdata.* .gnu.linkonce.s.* D_2 D_1)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    _edata = .;
    PROVIDE (edata = .);
    PROVIDE (__dataend = .);
  } > RAM AT> ROM

  /* Note that crt0 assumes this is a multiple of two; all the
     start/stop symbols are also assumed word-aligned.  */
  PROVIDE(__romdatastart = LOADADDR(.data));
  PROVIDE (__romdatacopysize = SIZEOF(.data));

  .bss :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__bssstart = .);
    *(.lower.bss.* .lower.bss)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.either.bss.* .either.bss)
    *(.dynbss)
    *(.sbss .sbss.*)
    *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(COMMON)
    PROVIDE (__bssend = .);
  } > RAM
  PROVIDE (__bsssize = SIZEOF(.bss));

  /* This section contains data that is not initialised at startup.  */
  .noinit :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__noinit_start = .);
    *(.noinit)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__noinit_end = .);
  } > RAM

  _end = .;
  PROVIDE (end = .);

  .stack (ORIGIN (RAM) + LENGTH(RAM)) :
  {
    PROVIDE (__stack = .);
    *(.stack)
  }


  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.lower.text.* .lower.text)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .text:*)

    KEEP (*(.text.*personality*))
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
    *(.interp .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version*)
    PROVIDE (__etext = .);
    PROVIDE (_etext = .);
    PROVIDE (etext = .);
    . = ALIGN(2);
    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))
    KEEP (*(.tm_clone_table))
  } > ROM

  .upper.text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.upper.text.* .upper.text)
  } > HIROM

  .infoA     : {} > INFOA              /* MSP430 INFO FLASH MEMORY SEGMENTS */
  .infoB     : {} > INFOB
  .infoC     : {} > INFOC
  .infoD     : {} > INFOD

  /* Make sure that upper data sections are not used.  */
  .upper :
  {
    *(.upper.bss.* .upper.bss)
    *(.upper.data.* .upper.data)
    ASSERT (SIZEOF(.upper) == 0, "This MCU does not support placing read/write data into high memory");
  }

  /* The rest are all not normally part of the runtime image.  */

  .MP430.attributes 0 :
  {
    KEEP (*(.MSP430.attributes))
    KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes))
    KEEP (*(__TI_build_attributes))
  }

  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1.  */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions.  */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions.  */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }

  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) }
}
```

Full readelf output:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            Standalone App
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Texas Instruments msp430 microcontroller
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4400
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          126884 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x2d
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         5
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         21
  Section header string table index: 18

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .lowtext          PROGBITS        00004400 0000d4 00006c 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000446c 000140 000500 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00002400 000640 000002 00  WA  0   0  2
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          00002404 000644 00145c 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 5] .noinit           PROGBITS        00003860 0091ce 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 6] .text             PROGBITS        0000496e 000642 008b8c 00  AX  0   0  2
  [ 7] .upper.text       PROGBITS        00010000 0091ce 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 8] .MP430.attributes LOPROC+3        00000000 0091ce 0004f1 00      0   0  1
  [ 9] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 0096bf 0000a5 01  MS  0   0  1
  [10] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 009768 000470 00      0   0  8
  [11] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 009bd8 007212 00      0   0  1
  [12] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 010dea 001d63 00      0   0  1
  [13] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 012b4d 001e04 00   W  0   0  1
  [14] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 014954 000664 00      0   0  4
  [15] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 014fb8 001023 01  MS  0   0  1
  [16] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 015fdb 0020f1 00      0   0  1
  [17] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 0180d0 000300 00      0   0  8
  [18] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0183d0 0000cc 00      0   0  1
  [19] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 01849c 004eb0 10     20 1016  4
  [20] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 01d34c 001c56 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000432c 0x0000432c 0x00140 0x00140 R E 0x4
  LOAD           0x000140 0x0000446c 0x0000446c 0x00500 0x00500 RW  0x4
  LOAD           0x000640 0x00002400 0x0000496c 0x00002 0x00002 RW  0x4
  LOAD           0x000644 0x00002404 0x0000496e 0x00000 0x0145c RW  0x4
  LOAD           0x000642 0x0000496e 0x0000496e 0x08b8c 0x08b8c R E 0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .lowtext 
   01     .rodata 
   02     .data 
   03     .bss 
   04     .text
```

For the moment, I changed the linker script to just put the contents of .rodata
and .upper.rodata into their respective .text segments, which works, but that seems unelegant
when .rodata should be read only by virtue of being assigned to ROM in the first
place.

```
/* ============================================================================ */
/* Copyright (c) 2015, Texas Instruments Incorporated                           */
/*  All rights reserved.                                                        */
/*                                                                              */
/*  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without          */
/*  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions          */
/*  are met:                                                                    */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright           */
/*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.            */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright        */
/*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the      */
/*     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.     */
/*                                                                              */
/*  *  Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of      */
/*     its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived      */
/*     from this software without specific prior written permission.            */
/*                                                                              */
/*  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" */
/*  AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,       */
/*  THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR      */
/*  PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR            */
/*  CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,       */
/*  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,         */
/*  PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; */
/*  OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,    */
/*  WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR     */
/*  OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,              */
/*  EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.                          */
/* ============================================================================ */

/* This file supports MSP430F5529 devices. */
/* Version: 1.159 */
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */

/* Modified for building executables loaded through XBX bootloader */

OUTPUT_ARCH(msp430)
ENTRY(_start)

MEMORY {
  SFR              : ORIGIN = 0x0000, LENGTH = 0x0010 /* END=0x0010, size 16 */
  PERIPHERAL_8BIT  : ORIGIN = 0x0010, LENGTH = 0x00F0 /* END=0x0100, size 240 */
  PERIPHERAL_16BIT : ORIGIN = 0x0100, LENGTH = 0x0100 /* END=0x0200, size 256 */
  RAM              : ORIGIN = 0x2400, LENGTH = 0x2000 /* END=0x43FF, size 8192 */
  INFOMEM          : ORIGIN = 0x1800, LENGTH = 0x0200 /* END=0x19FF, size 512 as 4 128-byte segments */
  INFOA            : ORIGIN = 0x1980, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x19FF, size 128 */
  INFOB            : ORIGIN = 0x1900, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x197F, size 128 */
  INFOC            : ORIGIN = 0x1880, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x18FF, size 128 */
  INFOD            : ORIGIN = 0x1800, LENGTH = 0x0080 /* END=0x187F, size 128 */
  ROM (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x4400, LENGTH = 0xb000 /* END=0xF3FF, size 45056 */
  BSL              : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x0800
  USBRAM           : ORIGIN = 0x1C00, LENGTH = 0x0800
  HIROM (rx)       : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 0x000143FF
}

SECTIONS
{
  /* This is just for crt0.S and interrupt handlers.  */
  .lowtext           :
  {
    PROVIDE (_start = .);
    . = ALIGN(2);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.crt_*)))
    KEEP (*(.lowtext))
  } > ROM



  .data :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__datastart = .);
    *(.lower.data.* .lower.data)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.either.data.* .either.data)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    KEEP (*(.jcr))
    *(.data.rel.ro.local) *(.data.rel.ro*)
    *(.dynamic)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    KEEP (*(.gnu.linkonce.d.*personality*))
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
    *(.data1)
    *(.got.plt) *(.got)

    /* We want the small data sections together, so single-instruction offsets
       can access them all, and initialized data all before uninitialized, so
       we can shorten the on-disk segment size.  */
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.sdata .sdata.* .gnu.linkonce.s.* D_2 D_1)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    _edata = .;
    PROVIDE (edata = .);
    PROVIDE (__dataend = .);
  } > RAM AT> ROM

  /* Note that crt0 assumes this is a multiple of two; all the
     start/stop symbols are also assumed word-aligned.  */
  PROVIDE(__romdatastart = LOADADDR(.data));
  PROVIDE (__romdatacopysize = SIZEOF(.data));

  .bss :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__bssstart = .);
    *(.lower.bss.* .lower.bss)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.either.bss.* .either.bss)
    *(.dynbss)
    *(.sbss .sbss.*)
    *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(COMMON)
    PROVIDE (__bssend = .);
  } > RAM
  PROVIDE (__bsssize = SIZEOF(.bss));

  /* This section contains data that is not initialised at startup.  */
  .noinit :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__noinit_start = .);
    *(.noinit)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    PROVIDE (__noinit_end = .);
  } > RAM

  _end = .;
  PROVIDE (end = .);

  .stack (ORIGIN (RAM) + LENGTH(RAM)) :
  {
    PROVIDE (__stack = .);
    *(.stack)
  }


  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.lower.text.* .lower.text)

    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.* .text:*)

    KEEP (*(.text.*personality*))
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
    *(.interp .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version*)
    PROVIDE (__etext = .);
    PROVIDE (_etext = .);
    PROVIDE (etext = .);
    . = ALIGN(2);
    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))
    KEEP (*(.tm_clone_table))


    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.plt)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.lower.rodata.* .lower.rodata)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.* .const .const:*)
    *(.rodata1)

    *(.eh_frame_hdr)
    KEEP (*(.eh_frame))
    KEEP (*(.gcc_except_table)) *(.gcc_except_table.*)
    PROVIDE (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE (__preinit_array_end = .);
    PROVIDE (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array))
    PROVIDE (__init_array_end = .);
    PROVIDE (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.fini_array))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    PROVIDE (__fini_array_end = .);
    LONG(0); /* Sentinel.  */

    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of the constructors, so
       we make sure it is first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not actually link against
       crtbegin.o; the linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it doesn't matter which
       directory crtbegin.o is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin*.o(.ctors))

    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from from the
       crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.  The .ctor section
       from the crtend file contains the end of ctors marker and it
       must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend*.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))

    KEEP (*crtbegin*.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend*.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))

  } > ROM

  .upper.text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.upper.text.* .upper.text)
    *(.upper.rodata.* .upper.rodata)
  } > HIROM

  .infoA     : {} > INFOA              /* MSP430 INFO FLASH MEMORY SEGMENTS */
  .infoB     : {} > INFOB
  .infoC     : {} > INFOC
  .infoD     : {} > INFOD

  /* Make sure that upper data sections are not used.  */
  .upper :
  {
    *(.upper.bss.* .upper.bss)
    *(.upper.data.* .upper.data)
    ASSERT (SIZEOF(.upper) == 0, "This MCU does not support placing read/write data into high memory");
  }

  /* The rest are all not normally part of the runtime image.  */

  .MP430.attributes 0 :
  {
    KEEP (*(.MSP430.attributes))
    KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes))
    KEEP (*(__TI_build_attributes))
  }

  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1.  */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions.  */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions.  */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }

  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ld documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170630153712/https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/memory.html): "The attr string is an optional list of attributes that specify whether to use a particular memory region for an input section which is not explicitly mapped in the linker script." - so `rx` in `ROM (rx) ...` is ignored.

[A mailing list post](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/binutils/2006-01/msg00115.html) indicates that this is due to a read-write flag being set on an input section. To fix this, I had to move all the c++ stuff in .rodata after .rodata1 to its own section.